# Get-SPSite in Powershell Script

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a script to deploy my solution which has some "Site" scoped features. In my script I am trying to get hold of Site Collection first like

```
$SiteCollection=Get-SPSite http://<server>/mysite
```

When I check SiteCollection -ne $null it always returns null but the same cmdlet works fine at command prompt.

Do not know whats wrong with my script.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a permissions issue.  When run from the command prompt, you have permission to get the Sharepoint site. Investigate how you're running your script when it doesn't work.  Make sure the user has permission.